# Fastest way to combine and normalise data from mutiple multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, numpy

I have a set of data which has three dimensions X,Y,Z of order 24,67,95
and 8 variables: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

Each variable is stored in an [X,Y,Z] numpy array(), i.e. with 24*67*95=152760 values.

The arrays are combined into an OrderedDict() with the keys being the names of the variables.

So, the value of variable a for the dimension x,y,z is given by data['a'][x][y][z]

I want to insert this data into a MySQL table in a normalised format, which is indexed by x,y,z:

```
 ---------------------
|x|y|z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|
 ---------------------
| | | | | | | | | | | |
```

I am doing this in the following manner, which generates an insert statement of 67*95 = 6365 entries at each step of x, which I understand is an optimal order of magnitude for MySQL:

```
cur = db.cursor()
Xs = 24
Ys = 67
Zs = 95    
variables = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
for x in range(Xs):
    sql="insert into mytable (X,Y,Z"
    for variable in variables:
        sql+=","+variable
    sql+=") values"
    for y in range(Ys):
        for z in range(Zs):
            sql+="(%d,%d,%d" % (x,y,z)
            for variable in variables:
                sql+=","+str(data[variable][x][y][z])
            sql+="),"
    cur.execute(sql[:-1])
```

The loop overall takes ~24 seconds to run for each iteration of X on my quad-core PC, with only around ~0.5s of that taken up by executing the insert statement.

Is there a faster way to combine and normalise these variables in memory?

(I am aware that the normalised database may not be the optimal storage format for such multi-dimensional data, and this is something I will subsequently be testing - for the purposes of this question, assume that it is)

Thanks!

Comment: Tried your code with generated floats and just generating a long string with the SQL commands - it only took less than 2.5 seconds on my laptop. If I understood your post right, you have 24*67*95*8 numbers. Something else seems to eat your time.

Comment: Two small suggestions: (1) Numpy arrays are indexed as `array[x,y,z]` but you used `array[x][y][z]`. (2) Collect the parts of the SQL command in a list and do a `str.join` in the end, to avoid allocating an increasingly long string each time (you can't really append to a string in Python as they are immutable).

Comment: Maybe even better, call the `tolist()` method on the arrays and index the nested list, because its faster than indexing a numpy array.

Comment: did you try numpy record arrays? that way you just have a 4D numpy array in which you can work with your variable names as well

Comment: Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/users/1879010/dietrich - because of your answer I investigated further, and it seems that the structure of the dataset I was accessing may be more complex than I realised, slowing down the operation to access each element. By extracting the arrays from the dataset into the form described before processing, it now takes 0.2s per iteration, without changing anything else. Still not sure exactly why the initial data structure was so slow, but at least it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the piece of code, I think there are a number of things that can be improved. Here's my take:

```
cur = db.cursor()
Xs = 24
Ys = 67
Zs = 95    
variables = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
sql = ("INSERT INTO mytable (X, Y, Z, " +
       ', '.join(variables) +
       ') VALUES ({0})').format(','.join(['%s'] * (len(variables) + 3)))

for x in range(Xs):
    for y in range(Ys):
        values = []
        for z in range(Zs):
            values = [x, y, z]
            for variable in variables:
                values.append(data[variable][x][y][z])
            cur.execute(sql, values)
```

The SQL statement is only created once. The values are stored in a list which is passed when to the `execute()` method of the cursor.

What you do to improve it further is to store all values in a list and use `executemany()`.

```
all_values = []
for x in range(Xs):
    for y in range(Ys):
        values = []
        for z in range(Zs):
            values = [x, y, z]
            for variable in variables:
                values.append(data[variable][x][y][z])
            all_values.append(values)

cur.executemany(sql, all_values)
```

I could not test the above as I don't have test data, but I hope it's clear as to what changed.

Comment: As in my comment above, it seems as though the call to access the original data structure element by element was the slow part, and by extracting all data into a new dictionary the process has been sped up by over 100 times. However, I also implemented your solution and it doubled the speed again, so I will mark this as the correct answer for the problem as stated. Thanks!